# Where can i find the implementation of SPIED tool from stanford corenlp?

Tags: stanford-nlp

In the paper, "*Improved Pattern Learning for Bootstrapped Entity Extraction. Sonal Gupta and Christopher D. Manning. In Proceedings of the Eighteenth Conference on Computational Natural Language Learning (CoNLL). 2014.*"
cited for the tool the link for implementation has been specified as http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/patternviz.shtml but it seems to be taken down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! We should maybe fix that; but, in the meantime the new link is: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/patternslearning.html. The code is distributed with Stanford CoreNLP, so there's no extra download. An example invocation is:

```
java -cp stanford-corenlp-3.5.1.jar:stanford-corenlp-3.5.1-models.jar:javax.json.jar:joda-time.jar:jollyday.jar edu.stanford.nlp.patterns.GetPatternsFromDataMultiClass -props patterns/example.properties
```